# Are batarangs aerodynamic enough to fly?

Tags: dc, batman, weapon

There some pretty funky batarang designs:

[image: Funky Batarang]
[image: Plain Batarang]
[image: Another funky one, collapsible?]

Are any of these, or batman's other designs actually aerodynamic?

Is there a replica that can be thrown like batman does, not just as an odd-shaped throwing *knife* but like a boomerang that curves in flight?

To clarify for recent answers, I'm not asking if the batarangs specifically return to the user,  but if they a) can fly when thrown and potentially hit a target and b) take *a curved flight path* as is often shown in the cartoons.

Comment: My wish: wake up tomorrow and find a post by Jeff Atwood who spent the weekend aerodynamically testing the models in a scientific way :)

Comment: far more important than would it fly is how the heck would you throw it with enough force to stay in the air without cutting yourself :)

Comment: @DVK I feel bad that the guy with the world's largest collection of boomerangs got **downvoted into oblivion**.

Comment: @Richard - because he didn't provide any proof that he didn't just make that up (I didn't DV, for the record, so not sure why the comment is addressed to me :) ). I would upvote if he posted some proof.

Comment: @DVK It was addressed to you because you mentioned aerodynamic testing. For the record, I *did* downvote because he didn't give any proof, I'm just feeling bad about it is all.

Comment: Plus I would think that batman would want them to stick where he threw them so his enemies could see what they were. The purpose of the batsuit is to strike fear into his enemies. Why shouldn't his weapons have the same effect?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Judging from the throwing knives of history, the shape of the weapon is secondary to its balance for throwing. While many batarangs tended to resemble boomerangs they tended to function more like shuriken, used to distract, cut or disarm Batman's opponents.**

### **Japan**

Shuriken, also called "the sword hidden in the hand" come in a variety of shapes and can be made from a wide array of things including nails, needles, knives as well as washers, coins and other plates of flat metal. The major varieties of shuriken are the bō shuriken (stick shuriken) and the hira shuriken (flat shuriken) or shaken (also read as kurumaken, wheel shuriken). Mastery of the tactical use of shuriken was called shurikenjutsu and was considered an effective if supplementary weapon to be used by a samurai warrior.

[image: Bō shuriken]

*Bō shuriken*

[image: Shuriken in a variety of shapes and sizes.]

*Hira shuriken in a variety of shapes and sizes.*

### **Africa**

The ndumo/mabo throwing knife, commonly used in Central Africa by the Mabo tribes was both a savage hand to hand weapon and able to be thrown accurately up to thirty feet. Made of iron, it could weigh upwards of two to four pounds.

[image: ndumo/mabo throwing knife, from Central Africa, used by the mabo Tribes]

Another well known, unusually shaped African weapon was the Kpinga. It was a multi-bladed throwing knife used by the Zande Warrior. The Kpinga had three projecting blades and a small, plant fiber handle. The one shown was 21 inches long and weighed 3.5 pounds. Like its distant cousin, the shuriken, it could be thrown overhead at an opponent, or sideways to take out an opponent's legs. Even the handle could do a lot of damage if it hit.

[image: Kpinga, from Central Africa]

*Kpinga, from Central Africa*

### **Australia**

Given that boomerangs also come in a variety of shapes, two, three and even four winged varieties, Batarangs, as long as they were balanced and shaped properly should be no less aerodynamic and equally effective if they are armed with explosives or gas-based weapons.

[image: Boomerangs, two, three and four winged]

*Boomerangs, two, three and four winged*

**Of course, the real question, is where do you get someone to manufacture BAT-shaped boomerangs, throwing knives and shuriken without asking any questions?**

Comment: It's easy: the same place where you get trick arrows!

Comment: Plus one for the second sentence.

Comment: maybe he should start 3d printing them. it's the cool thing to do now

Comment: "Of course, the real question, is where do you get someone to manufacture BAT-shaped boomerangs, throwing knives and shuriken without asking any questions?" -- see my answer; custom boomerang manufacturer who happens to be into this, basically..

Answer (score 11):

As part of the DC Nation cartoon block, some comic book weapons are built and then are shown working.  The first one was for the [batarang](http://vimeo.com/40278568).  Although the design they used doesn't match the ones in the question, it shows that at least with practice, it's possible to throw one accurately.

Comment: That's crazy! But also just an odd-shaped throwing knife. Still a good find!

Comment: @Pureferret: Does Batman ever use batarangs as returning boomerangs? Real-life returning boomerangs can be [any shape](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ip7H9Btv8s), but they're used for sport only. Hunting boomerangs aren't designed to return. In any case, as soon as a boomerang strikes a target, it falls to the ground and won't return anyhow. And retrieving a returning boomerang requires you to track its flight circle, which isn't practical during a fight. Having a bunch of non-returning boomerangs/shurikens seems more combat effective.

Comment: Yes, batman has used them as returning boomerang often in cartoons

Answer (score 3):

Well, even though this question has an accepted answer, I feel compelled to provide the following; Not only is it possible to use it as a shuriken... but a returning boomerang is quite possible:

(This one produced by [Boomerangs by Vic](http://boomerangsbyvic.com/)  -- now, you not only know it works, but can order one online.)

First, a Youtube link to his original attempt:

And his new version:

Answer (score 2):

Someone gave me a set of the ones in the second picture. They work perfectly as throwing knife, but no, they do not return.

Why would ou want them to? If you missed your target, they wouldn't return directly to you, and if they did how would you catch one that's sharp enough to be useful as a weapon?

Comment: Especially if the batarang contains explosives... In any case, it doesn't seem like batarangs are used as returning boomerangs (though some are more like hunting boomerangs than shurikens or throwing knives): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlV_Tk1-_U0

Comment: I think that the returning quality is probably less important than the ability to curve flight, at least based on Batman's usual usage where they seem to come in at all angles.